# How do I choose a replacement wheel rim?

Tags: parts, rims, rear-wheel, replacement, wheel-building

These are my current rims: Wheeltech TD26 by Alex Rims (can't find much info about these online).  I need to replace the rear wheel as it is cracked (cracks on the rims around a few spokes)
It's a 700C disc brake rim with quick releases.  What do I need to consider other than the size of the wheel when choosing a replacement?  I'll likely migrate over the cassette and rotor (if need be).  My knowledge of rims is limited so any help is appreciated!

Here is my bike: https://www.bikes.com/en/bikes/whistler/2015 (Must select Whistler 70 when on the site)

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to decide whether you want to replace the rim (the ring shaped outer part) or entire wheel. If the wheel is otherwise in good shape, swapping the rim is an easy task and a shop should charge less than for a full rebuild.

For wheel you have to match size, axle thickness, spacing and cassette and brake disk interface. Fortunately, for quick releases there is only one common axle and spacing standard. If you want to keep the discs, you will need hub with Centerlock rotor interface. For cassette interface, the common exceptions are 11-speed road, Campagnolo and Sram XD, and your bike doesn't have any of these. In practice this means you'll want a Shimano hub.

If you swap the rim, you'll need to match size, spoke count and ERD, the diameter at spoke holes. Rim width does not need to be exact match, but if you are using the same tires it shouldn't be changed much. A rim with different ERD requires new spokes and relacing the wheel from scratch.

Comment: I agree the OP should consider having a shop rebuild it with a new rim. I'd argue that the OP does **not** need to re-use the spokes. Spokes are cheap. Removing them and keeping them straight may be an issue - I've never tried rebuilding a wheel with the same spokes, but I suspect they can get bent out of shape when de-lacing. The OP would just need a new rim with the same spoke count as before (32 holes).

Comment: @WeiwenNg - Actually, reusing the spokes on a simple rim replacement is far easier than replacing them -- the only issue is the wear-and-tear on the spokes from being loosened and retightened.  There's no need for the spokes to be completely removed -- just transferred one at a time from old rim to new.

Comment: Rim width also needs to be suitable for the tires the OP wants to use.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I concede the point. Thanks for pointing that out!